# How can I handle Future methods to refresh colors of my polygons in the map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, polygon

I am new to programming in Flutter, I have a screen that loads a Google Maps map, this map contains several polygons, these polygons have an Id, a list of coordinates assigned to them. Likewise, I have a database in firestore that has records with 4 fields:
'sector_id' int,
'date' datetime,
'incident_type' string,
'description' string.
Through a method that, depending on the number of records in firestore, paints the polygon with 1 color. I'm attempting to do is change the color of a polygon on my google map, after it's already been added to the map. when there is a change in the database (**In real time**)

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hello/src/services/view_report_page.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'services/create_report_page.dart';

enum Options { search, upload, exit }

class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  MapsDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  @override
  State<MapsDemo> createState() => MapsDemoState();
}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {
  late Timer _timer;
  late GoogleMapController _mapController;
  Set<Polygon> sectorUno = HashSet<Polygon>();
  LatLng? currentLocation;
  int currentSector = 0;
  Future<Position> determinePosition() async {
    LocationPermission permission;
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('error');
      }
    }
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position = await determinePosition();
    setState(() {
      currentLocation = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    });
  }

  Map<String, Marker> _markers = {};
  //sign out user method
  void signUserOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  List<LatLng> ayacucho = [xxxxxxx];

  List<LatLng> olmedo = [xxxxxxxx];

  List<LatLng> bolivar = [xxxxxx];

  List<LatLng> rocaFuerte = [xxxxxx];

 FirebaseFirestore db= FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CollectionReference? collectionReferenceRegister;

  Future<Color> getColor(int idSector) async {
    List register = [];
    int _counter = 0;
    QuerySnapshot queryRegister = await collectionReferenceRegister!
        .where("id_sector", isEqualTo: idSector)
        /*.where("dateField", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDate)
        .where("dateField", isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDate)*/
        .get();

    for (var document in queryRegister.docs) {
      register.add(document.data());
    }
    _counter = queryRegister.docs.length;
    setState(() {});
    if (_counter <= 6) {
      return Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5);
    }if (_counter >= 7 && _counter <= 14) {
      return Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.5);
    } else {
      return Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5);


    }

  }

  Future<void> addSectorPolygon(int idSector, List<LatLng> points) async {
    Color color = await getColor(idSector);
    sectorUno.add(Polygon(
      polygonId: PolygonId(idSector.toString()),
      points: points,
      fillColor: color,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeWidth: 2,
    ));
  }

  Future<void> _addAllSectors() async{
    await Future.wait([
      addSectorPolygon(1, ayacucho),
      addSectorPolygon(2, olmedo),
      addSectorPolygon(3, bolivar),
      addSectorPolygon(4, rocaFuerte),
      addSectorPolygon(5, carbo),
      addSectorPolygon(6, nueveOctubre),
      addSectorPolygon(7, roca),
      addSectorPolygon(8, sucre),
      addSectorPolygon(9, garciaMoreno),
      addSectorPolygon(10, urdaneta),
      addSectorPolygon(11, letamendi),
      addSectorPolygon(12, ximena),
      addSectorPolygon(13, febresCordero),
      addSectorPolygon(14, tarqui),
      addSectorPolygon(15, pascuales),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();
    collectionReferenceRegister = db.collection('registroIncidentes');
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        _addAllSectors();
      });
    });
    collectionReferenceRegister!.snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {

    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Ubicacion actual'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            offset: const Offset(0, kToolbarHeight),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            itemBuilder: (ctx) {
              return [
                const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                    value: 0,
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
                      Text(' Ver registro de zona')
                    ])),
                const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                    value: 1,
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Icon(Icons.upload, color: Colors.black),
                      Text(' Crear Registros de zona')
                    ])),
                const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                    value: 2,
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Icon(Icons.exit_to_app, color: Colors.black),
                      Text(' Desconectar')
                    ]))
              ];
            },
            onSelected: (value) async {
              currentSector = sectorValidation();
              switch (value) {
                case 0:
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ViewReportPage(currentSector)));
                  break;
                case 1:
                   Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              CreateReportPage(currentSector)));
                  break;
                case 2:
                  signUserOut();
                  break;
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: currentLocation == null
          ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          : GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: currentLocation!,
                zoom: 16,
              ),
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              onMapCreated: (controller) {
                _mapController = controller;
                addMarker('Ubicacion actual', currentLocation!);
              },
              polygons: sectorUno,
              markers: _markers.values.toSet(),
            ),
    );
  }

  addMarker(String id, LatLng location) async {
    var marker = Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(id),
      position: location,
    );
    _markers[id] = marker;
    setState(() {});
  }

  bool _checkIfValidMarker(LatLng tap, List<LatLng> vertices) {
    int intersectCount = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < vertices.length - 1; j++) {
      if (rayCastIntersect(tap, vertices[j], vertices[j + 1])) {
        intersectCount++;
      }
    }

    return ((intersectCount % 2) == 1); // odd = inside, even = outside;
  }

  bool rayCastIntersect(LatLng tap, LatLng vertA, LatLng vertB) {
    double aY = vertA.latitude;
    double bY = vertB.latitude;
    double aX = vertA.longitude;
    double bX = vertB.longitude;
    double pY = tap.latitude;
    double pX = tap.longitude;

    if ((aY > pY && bY > pY) || (aY < pY && bY < pY) || (aX < pX && bX < pX)) {
      return false;
    }
    double m = (aY - bY) / (aX - bX);
    double bee = (-aX) * m + aY;
    double x = (pY - bee) / m;
    return x > pX;
  }

  int sectorValidation() {
    int idSector = 0;
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, ayacucho) == true) {
      idSector = 1;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, olmedo) == true) {
      idSector = 2;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, bolivar) == true) {
      idSector = 3;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, rocaFuerte) == true) {
      idSector = 4;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, carbo) == true) {
      idSector = 5;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, nueveOctubre) == true) {
      idSector = 6;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, roca) == true) {
      idSector = 7;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, sucre) == true) {
      idSector = 8;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, garciaMoreno) == true) {
      idSector = 9;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, urdaneta) == true) {
      idSector = 10;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, letamendi) == true) {
      idSector = 11;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, ximena) == true) {
      idSector = 12;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, febresCordero) == true) {
      idSector = 13;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, tarqui) == true) {
      idSector = 14;
    }
    if (_checkIfValidMarker(currentLocation!, pascuales) == true) {
      idSector = 15;
    }
    return idSector;
  }
}
```